# Xamarin Android Webview Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, webview

I am trying to create a mobile app via Xamarin for Android which has a WebView that shows a website, problem is that normal buttons fire, but javascript events do not fire. I have enabled Javascript, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to enable javascript in your android webview include the following code in MainActivity.OnCreate:

```
localWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
localWebView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
```

The first allows javascript to work, the second will allow values to be stored in your HTML/DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to insecure content stuff that is introduced in lollipop.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
     webView.Settings.MixedContentMode = MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow;
```

Try adding these lines and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Had a bit of trouble with this myself for anyone working on this.
The below helped.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-hybrid-android/9781449361907/ch04.html

My issue was I was expecting web javascript functionality from a default browser and had not call webView.SetWebChromeClient(new Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient());
Needs to be called in customer renderer

After this webview started performing at intended