# We are facing issues with xamarin Android ,where in Web browser "status 404,resourse not found " error is displayed when we do a SSO Login

Tags: javascript, xamarin.android

We are facing issues with xamarin Android ,where in Web browser "status 404,resourse not found " error is displayed when we do a SSO Login

when we tried to log we found
EVENT - "\n \u003Cdiv id="noScript" style="position: static; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 100; display: none;">\n \u003Ch1>JavaScript required\u003C/h1>\n \u003Cp>JavaScript is required. This web browser does not support JavaScript or J - {}

users must be able to login without issues

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! i believe a [tour] and a visit on [ask] would do good to improve your question clarity. it would be even better if you can provide [mcve]. i'm still not sure what this SSO related to xamarin and the javascript problem. did you by any chance using xamarin's `WebView`? if yes, possibly [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911464/xamarin-android-webview-javascript) can serve as reference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.